# match against, sort by relevance

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

My Query

```
$query = selectQuery('SELECT * FROM page_info WHERE MATCH(content) 
           AGAINST("reactie klanten" WITH QUERY EXPANSION)');
```

how can I sort by relevance? i get back about 10 rows, but the row that actually contains the words 'reactie' and 'klanten' is somewhere in the middle. the rest of the results is somehow relevant with the words :S

[MySQL documentation about 'WITH QUERY EXPANSION'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-query-expansion.html)

**EDIT**
changed by query to:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(content) AGAINST("reactie klanten") AS relevance FROM page_info WHERE MATCH(content) AGAINST("reactie klanten" WITH QUERY EXPANSION) ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

this seems promising, because now the field is on top of the list.

still how are the others related?

example:

```
 $text  = This page is being tested by our tester
```

how is $text relevant to `reactie klanten`?

Comment: `QUERY EXPANSION` will do that... Do you need it?

Comment: I know WITH QUERy EXPANSION adds relevant pages, but how is 'this page is being test...' related to 'reactie klanten'.

Comment: Without the actual content of your database, hard to tell from here ;)